# Wordpress Divi Builder - Change Background color not working

Tags: wordpress

I am currently editing a website and I want to change the background color of a module but unfortunately, it is not working. I tried to press the plus sign multiple times but it does not show the color palette.
I searched a lot but I really cannot find the solution.
Any help? Thanks!

[pic here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBo0H.jpg)

Comment: do you see some error in the browser console?

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. I just updated Divi Builder, which didn't help, but once I updated the Divi theme it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: The Divi theme update fixed the issue for me. Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Quick fix! only Incase you don't dont want to update the Divi theme just update this css: /Divi/includes/styles/styles.css

Insert this css @ line :73

`.wp-picker-container a span{position: relative!important;}`

The issue resides from the color span having a position:absolute;

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it for me. However I couldn't find a style sheet at that location. I added the line to the style sheet at 
/Divi/includes/builder/styles/styles.css

Answer (score 1):

yeah that was an issue with older version of divi, it's solved in latest version.

but still if someone is looking for an answer, try bellow options.

**Solution:**

1: use custom css to change the color of background, go to the custom css and add `background-color: #000;` to main section.

2: use the backend builder of divi.

3: Update your divi theme.

4: Downgrade your wordpress to 4.8

5: if you are good with  debugging css issues then go to inspect element and make the `display: visible; opacity: 1;` for a specific element.

hope this would solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

It almost seems as if there is a colour already. Hover your mouse to the top right corner of the colour window and tilt your head a bit down. Check to see if you find a cog-wheel or a dustbin icon and click either one of the two. The cog-wheel will bring up the colour palette and the dustbin will trash the current colour.

Note: Because of some screens (like mine) the cog-wheel and dustbin are difficult to see unless you tilt your head and you basically look up at it and not straight at it.